# Bubble type diagram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create this chart from data with 2 factors

[whats needed](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZJ31x7ZgH7RCtqNruLU7OEPhjj1I8cbKkbX)

[image: whats needed]

the data is three columns, an ID, a factor ( 1 or 2) and a value (1-200) there are 45,000 rows.

```
dput(head(d))
structure(list(ID = 1:6, variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("on.tank", "on.main"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0, 41, 0, 2, 0, 1)), .Names = c("ID", "variable", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried several goes with ggplot2:

```
ggplot(d3, aes(ID,abs.sol, col=variable)) + 
geom_point(aes(size = abs.sol)) +
theme(text = element_text(size=15)) +
scale_y_continuous(labels=abs)
```

and

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = factor(1), y = value)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = variable, shape = variable), 
              width = 0.1, size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) + 
  labs(x = NULL)   # Remove x axis label
```

and

```
ggplot(d3, aes(x = factor(1), y = abs.sol)) +
    geom_jitter(aes(color = variable, shape = variable), 
              width = 0.1, size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) + 
  labs(x = NULL)   # Remove x axis label
```

The results are in these images:

[image1](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZcv1x7ZjdlQFmqbOhBqsWkwVlk50YQipkry)
[image: image1]

[image2](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZ47ex7Zc3XrSsVDgo7jjsa3jPK7JV67dzAV)
[image: image2]

[image3](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZkkex7ZAKfeuDtAK9FKDf3NsTqRefLoIJHk)
[image: image3]

Image3 shows the data that I am trying to simplify to the above bubble diagram. I want color to represent the factor (1 or 2), the size to represent the COUNT of each value (i.e. how many 75's are in the data)and the actual value (e.g. "75" to be as text in the bubble).

Comment: Please paste images(**For plots**) in your question not links to an image.  I can for instance not access the link to the cloud.

Comment: I can't; I need a reputation of 10 to do so. Do you get and error with the link?

Comment: Yes. The link doesn't open for me. Not sure why.

Comment: In data you provided there's on column factor 1,2 and no COUNT column. Please update your example.

Comment: It's also unclear why you added plots with jitter and bar when you want plot with `geom_point` (bubbles).

Comment: what are the ``x``, ``y`` exactly in the plot you want? (is it ``x=Value`` and ``y=Count``), and I'm assuming here that the ``Count`` is the count of each ``Value`` per ``Factor``.

To be honest what you want is still not clear.

Comment: Sorry its not clear. There is no COUNT column as I assumed would wrangle the data further to get the count of the values. The factors are the "on.tank" and "on.main, which in another version of my trials were chnaged to 1 and 2 so some of the dplyer attempts would not throw an error..

Comment: ![result1](https://imgur.com/wK9Rs7y)

Comment: https://imgur.com/wK9Rs7y

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your data set is appropriate to bubble plot. Bubble plot is to draw three variable, i.e. *multivariate case*, `x`, `y`, and the other `z`.

But here I cannot see any `x` and `y`.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
(mydf <-
  data_frame(
    ID = 1:50,
    value = sample(1:50, 50, replace = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  add_column(variable = gl(2, k = 25, labels = c("on.tank", "on.main")), .before = 2))
#> # A tibble: 50 x 3
#>       ID variable value
#>    <int> <fct>    <int>
#>  1     1 on.tank     14
#>  2     2 on.tank     19
#>  3     3 on.tank     29
#>  4     4 on.tank     46
#>  5     5 on.tank     11
#>  6     6 on.tank     45
#>  7     7 on.tank     48
#>  8     8 on.tank     34
#>  9     9 on.tank     32
#> 10    10 on.tank      4
#> # ... with 40 more rows
```

To this data set, you can conduct `summarise(n())` or `tally()` for each group of (`variable, value`)

```
mydf %>% 
  count(variable, value) # equivalent to group_by() and tally()
#> # A tibble: 39 x 3
#> # Groups:   variable [?]
#>    variable value     n
#>    <fct>    <int> <int>
#>  1 on.tank      4     1
#>  2 on.tank      7     1
#>  3 on.tank      9     1
#>  4 on.tank     11     3
#>  5 on.tank     14     2
#>  6 on.tank     19     1
#>  7 on.tank     20     2
#>  8 on.tank     25     1
#>  9 on.tank     29     1
#> 10 on.tank     32     1
#> # ... with 29 more rows
```

`n` would be the bubble size.

```
mydf %>% 
  count(variable, value) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = value, y = n) +
  # geom_point(alpha = .5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), size = 2.5) +
  geom_point(aes(size = n, colour = variable), shape = 1) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 10), breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

Here we only have `value`-`count`. This is not multivariate problem. Since this is not of `x`-`y` with third variable, *bubble plot seems not that informative*. Changing size is just distractive.

---

### Alternatives

You can think another plots. For instance,

```
mydf %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = value) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ .)
```

[image]

You can compare two factors and count each value. I think this one is more helpful than bubble plot.

Since the number of data points is not small, histogram is also able to used: `geom_bar()`

```
mydf %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = value) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..count..)) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ .)
```

[image]

#### Large size of data set

```
set.seed(1)
(mydf2 <-
  data_frame(
    ID = 1:3000,
    value = sample(1:200, 3000, replace = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  add_column(variable = gl(2, k = 1500, labels = c("on.tank", "on.main")), .before = 2))
#> # A tibble: 3,000 x 3
#>       ID variable value
#>    <int> <fct>    <int>
#>  1     1 on.tank     54
#>  2     2 on.tank     75
#>  3     3 on.tank    115
#>  4     4 on.tank    182
#>  5     5 on.tank     41
#>  6     6 on.tank    180
#>  7     7 on.tank    189
#>  8     8 on.tank    133
#>  9     9 on.tank    126
#> 10    10 on.tank     13
#> # ... with 2,990 more rows
```

In the same process, histogram gives

```
mydf2 %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = value) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..count..)) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ .)
```

[image]

If you want to count the series of 10 days, the following might work:

```
mydf2 %>% 
  count(variable, value) %>% 
  filter(value == 10)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   variable value     n
#>   <fct>    <int> <int>
#> 1 on.tank     10     6
#> 2 on.main     10    10
```

Comment: so to explain a little; The results are of modelling a rainwater tank system which is also connected to the mains (129 years of daily data). sometimes it is on the tank for a series of days (the "value" in the data set where variable is "on.tank") and if the tank is empty it switches on to  the water main (the "value" in the data where the variable says "on.main"). The idea of the bubble is that I need to show for example how many sequences of length of 10 days (count the number of 10 day long sequences ) was the house on the tank. likewise for all sequence lengths on both tank and mains.

Comment: @ramonskovitch, If I understood right, you want to count each `value`(series of days) for each `on.tank` and `on.main`. I did also compute and visualize using dot plot and histogram. Is bubble plot necessary?

Comment: in the real data ther are over 3000 sequences varying in length from 1 to 200 days. I was looking to aggregation to better visualise the data. I am exploring using an x-axis of the actual years (129 years) or maybe of the decades?? with y- axis of the sequence lengths and a bubble size of the number of occurences of each sequence length in that year or decade. Have now added a variable which is the year so will see how that looks.

Answer (score 0):

In absence of proper data it is a little hard to understand what you try to achieve. But let's have a try anyways :)

First generate some random data according to your description:

```
require(tidyverse)    
TYPE = sample(c("factor 1","factor 2"),1000, replace=T)
VALUE = sample(1:200,1000,replace=T)
df = data.frame(TYPE, VALUE)
```

Time for some data wrangling and visualizing it. First taking your approach of counting individual value realizations:

```
df %>%
  group_by(TYPE, VALUE) %>%
  tally() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=VALUE, y=n, color = TYPE)) + geom_point(aes(size=n))
```

This does not look good - there are too many unique TYPE-VALUE combinations resulting in many small bubbles. Let's create rougher values by rounding to a grid of size 20:

```
df %>%
  mutate(VALUE = round(VALUE/20,0)*20) %>%
  group_by(TYPE, VALUE) %>%
  tally() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=VALUE, y=n, color = TYPE)) + geom_point(aes(size=n))
```

[image]

Comment: This works however it shows that in the 45,000 results there are many with a count of 1 making a crowded graph. I am thinking maybe a binning exercise rather than grid change might work, will exploreand come back [![enter image description here][1]]


  [1]: https://imgur.com/wK9Rs7y

Comment: replace the 20 by a greater value in  `mutate(VALUE = round(VALUE/20,0)*20) %>%` to try a coarser binning